# In AngularJS, how do I hide a DIV if Response Status to remote resource is 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a social media comments box on my page that I am loading using Angular.   Unfortunately, on some networks this box is blocked by network admins and an ugly error is displayed in its place.   I want to detect if the social media site is blocked, and if it is I want to display a more friendly, better looking, error message to the user.

I am running into a couple problems doing this.

First of all, if I encounter an error 'status' is coming back as 'undefined':

```
app.directive('dynFbLike', function ($http) {
    function createHTML(href, layout, action, showfaces, share) {
    $http.jsonp('//graph.socialmediasite.com/APIKEYWASHERE').
        success(function () {
            console.log('Loading "Like" badge...');
                return '<div class="fb-like" ' +
                               'data-href="' + href + '" ' +
                               'data-layout="' + layout + '" ' +
                               'data-action="' + action + '" ' +
                               'data-show-faces="' + showfaces + '" ' +
                               'data-share="' + share + '">' +
                       '</div>';
        }).
        error(function (status) {
            console.log('Status: ' + status);
            if (status == 403)
            {
                var errorMessage = 'This comments box is not accessible.  Please contact your network administrator for further information.';
                console.log(errorMessage);
                return errorMessage;    
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('pageHref', function (newValue) {
                var href        = newValue;
                var layout    = attrs.layout    || 'box_count';
                var action = attrs.action || 'like';
                var showfaces = attrs.showfaces || 'true';
                var share = attrs.share || 'true%';
                elem.html(createHTML(href, layout, action, showfaces, share));
                FB.XFBML.parse(elem[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Secondly, before I put the logic in to look at the specific error message, the error message was not being inserted in the page.

Comment: which version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: Error 403 is returned by your server, not by the admins

Comment: 1.3.0-beta.13 (also same behavior in beta.10)

Comment: @patxy No, 403 error is returned because proxy is blocking traffic to an external resource.  If I make the same request, while attached to a different network I do not get a 403 error.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code Sorry, I was thinking about a firewall blocking your IP

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the [API docs for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http).

The error callback actually has `data` as the first parameter and `status` as the second parameter:

```js
$http.jsonp('//graph.socialmediasite.com/APIKEYWASHERE').
  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did add data to it.   Now its spitting back 404 instead of the 403 that Chrome shows.  Weird.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code try checking for the status code in Firefox and using curl or some other command-line tool to confirm it isn't a browser issue? They might be checking for browsers and returning a 403 when it's a browser rather than a JSON request? You could try using some other method other than `$http.jsonp` as well?

Comment: I am open to ideas.   I switched to $http.jsonp as I was trying to get around the silly cross domain origin issues.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to use either `ng-hide` (or `ng-show`) in your template bound to a property in the scope set to false by default . If you get a 403 from your service, then set the property to true.

Here is a simple demonstration of ng-show: http://plnkr.co/edit/ilTJtO3UfMqGxL2g1bwr?p=preview

Comment: @MilenIgrachev -- not true. I forked your plunk, your controller wasn't working so I just deleted it. http://plnkr.co/edit/ilTJtO3UfMqGxL2g1bwr?p=preview